# Minimal frequency of standing waves in closed-open pipe with helium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

Given: closed-open pipe with Helium, density of the gas is ***P***, pipes length is ***l***. I have to find minimal frequency of standing waves in pipe

Picture: [image]

I have found some info about simple standing waves in closed and open pipes, but no info about pipes with some kind of gas in it. As I guess, speed in Helium will be higher, wavelength will remain the same. I didnt manage to find some formulas to take into account Helium and its density P.
Can you please give me some ideas or material where I should dig in. Thank you and sorry in advance for poor englando!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of the pipe determines the wavelength of the fundamental tone and its harmonics. To find their frequencies you need to know the speed of sound in helium and then use $v=f \lambda$ (speed of sound = frequency times wavelength).

Comment: Ah, thats easier than I thought. So, I just need to find speed of sound in helium known its density. Thank you.